# Xerces and Xalan-C for windows

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, xerces, xalan, vcproj

Would like to port Xerces and Xalan to latest Microsofy Visual Studio (2010).
For Xerces, all I have to do is download from site Xcerces version 3.1.1.
But it is not preintegrated with Xalan-C. only Xalan-C 1.10 and Xerces 2.7 are pre integrated.
Xalan Version 1.10 fails to compile on 2010.

Where can I find pre-integrated version of Xalan-C for Visual Studio 2010.

Thanks,
Eliakim

Answer (score 0):

Xalan-C 1.10 is the latest version, and it requires Xerces 2.7. So you will have to use these two versions together.

Comment: Thanks Martin, but I am looking for Visual Studion 2010 certification. Niether Xcerces not Xalan in the versions mentioned by you are 2010 certified

Comment: Well, do they compile with VS 2010? This is free software, so you may not be able to get anybody to "certify" it.

Answer (score 0):

http://xalan.apache.org/xalan-c/index.html  there appears to be an upcoming 1.11 release, the subversion trunk seems to compile ok against 3.1.1 though I don't know if it is final.